# Menu Fixo em Csharp

Tags: c#, .net

Gostaria de saber como faço para ter um menu fixo em c#, conforme o usuário mexa na aplicação, mude só o contexto, parecido com páginas Web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa eu posso respondeu (estou fazendo um formulário assim).

- Antes de tudo tu adiciona um `splitContainer` no seu formulário, após isso tu muda as propriedades dele (do `splitContainer` e não dos `panels`), e muda para `vertical` ou `horizontal` (de acordo com seu formulário)..

Caso queira deixar fixo, ou seja, para que o usuário não possa aumentar ou diminuir o tamanho dos painéis arrastando o separador, tu coloca `True` na propriedade `IsSplitterFix`.

- Agora você adiciona um `menuStrip` e coloca dentro do `panel1` do `splitContainer`, encaixe ele automaticamente no painel.
- Crie as opções do menu e os métodos para `Click` de cada uma(para isso dê duplo clique na opção), dentro do método tu coloca:

  ```
  private void novoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {//esse é meu metodo ao clicar no botao novo do menustrip
      NOME-SPLIT-CONTAINER.NOME-DO-PANEL.Controls.Clear(); // limpa o painel2
      FORM.TopLevel = false; // redefine um level do form (slit nao funciona com form de level superior)
      NOME-SPLIT-CONTAINER.NOME-DO-PANEL.Controls.Add(FORM); //add formulario ao painel 2
  //form é a instancia do formulário que tu quer exibir no panel2 do split, sugiro que crie uma instancia publica e estática
      FORM.Show(); // mostra formulario
  }
  ```

Para cada contexto você irá criar um `form`, e criar uma instancia dele no seu formulário principal (o que possui `splitContainer`), sugiro que essas instâncias sejam estáticas, para não ficar sujando a memória do PC, criando novas instâncias sempre que um form for chamado.

**Dica:** 
Coloque esse `form` com a mesma cor de background e sem janela (alterando a propriedade `FormBorderStyle` para `none`), assim você dará um aspecto que é o mesmo formulário.

**Extra:**
Como tu disse 'páginas de web' se tu quiser é só criar um `form` com `WebBrowser` e exibir ele no `panel2`.

EDIT

Caso Você já tinha visto, o `form` que tu vai inserir dento do `panel` ficará sempre no canto superior esquerdo do `panel` para corrigir isso e deixa-lo no centro, ou como você queira, crie o `form`, normalmente, após isso selecione todos os itens que você tem nele e tira a âncora dos mesmo.. Para isso vá em `Propriedades`, em `anchor` deixe `none`.

Agora outra coisa importante, caso seu `form` seja maior (em altura ou largura) que o `panel` em que você deseja exibi-lo, adicione ao código de cima, as seguintes linhas, lembrando que as linhas serão adicionadas antes de colocar o `form` no `panel` (ou seja, antes do `Controls.Add`):

```
int altura = this.NOME-SPLIT-CONTAINER.NOME-DO-PANEL.Height;
int largura = this.NOME-SPLIT-CONTAINER.NOME-DO-PANEL.Width;
FORM.Height = altura;
FORM.Width = largura;
```

Assim você faz com que seu `form` receba a mesma altura e largura do seu `panel`, se o seu `form` for muito extenso na altura é só apagar as linhas da `altura`, assim ele só irá mostra um scroll vertical , sem scroll horizontal (que pra mim é um saco).